# Enviando uma imagem de uma página para outra (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, link

Tenho uma galeria de imagens carregadas de maneira dinâmica, onde o usuário busca pela categoria e o sistema carrega as imagens referentes.
Abaixo de cada uma das imagens carregadas tem um button, que quando clicado, a imagem referente ao button deve ser exibida em uma div na nova página.

**Imagem dos buttons aos quais me referi:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é em relação de como fazer isso, deixarei aqui abaixo os códigos.

**VIEW onde a galeria com as imagens são carregadas:**

```
<div class="container-galeria row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <?php foreach ($listagem as $foto) : ?>
                    <div class="card mx-3 my-3" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/upload/<?= $foto['caminhoImagem']?>" alt="<?= $foto['tituloImagem']?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?= $foto['tituloImagem']?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text"><?= $foto['dscImagem']?></p>
                            <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">icone aqui</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
```

**VIEW onde a imagem será exibida na nova página:**

```
<div class="area-imagem">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com a class **FTP** do **codeigniter** configure a segunda conexão do banco para logo após fazer a inserção, edição ou excluir os dados, o php salva o arquivo na hospedagem em uma pasta temporaria e executo o seguinte script:

```
  $caminho_temp= "Arquivos/TEMP/DE/{$this->input->post('numero')}_{$this->input->post('ano')}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";

  $source = $caminho_temp;
    $this->load->library('ftp');
    //FTP configuration
    $ftp_config['hostname'] = '###.150.##.123';
    $ftp_config['username'] = '@@@@@@';
    $ftp_config['password'] = '@@@@@@';
    $ftp_config['debug']    = FALSE;

    //Connect to the remote server
    if($this->ftp->connect($ftp_config) == TRUE){

      //File upload path of remote server
      $destino = "/Arquivos/DE/{$fileName}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";
      $destino_url = "Arquivos/DE/{$fileName}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";

      //Upload file to the remote server
      $this->ftp->upload($source, ".".$destino);

      //Close FTP connection
      $this->ftp->close();
      @unlink($source);
    }else{
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Problema de conexão com o servidor de documentos.');
      @unlink($source);
      redirect(base_url()."admin/atos/de/editar/".$this->input->post('id'));
    }
```

Após efetuar o envio pelo FTP exclua o arquivo da pasta temporária na hospedagem ou caso teve falha no envio também a exclua.

Processo pode ficar um pouco lento para arquivos maiores de 5mb.